# Gravação no DB não funciona quando uso alertigo.js

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Tenho um codigo para atualizar e deletar dados no banco de dados so que infelizmente sê mostrar o alert personalizado no ecrâ então não grava na banco de dados e nem atualiza a página más sê gravar então não apresenta o alert personalizado.

Estou usando `alertigo.js` e modal.

Tem algum jeito de como fazer de modo ao atualizar dados ou ao deletar ele mostra esta alert personalizado e grava os dados no banco? Já pesquizei tanto e não encontrei algo que podesse me ajudar.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_evento" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Funcionario</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default ">
                            <div class="panel-heading funcionario"></div>
                            <div class="panel-body funcao">Panel Content</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form method="POST"  id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_func" id="id_func">
                        <input type="hidden" name="nome" id="nome">
                        <input type="hidden" name="funcao" id="funcao">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-residente" class="control-label">Residência (Sua residência atual):</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="residente" id="residente" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-naturalidade">Natural de:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="naturalidade" name="naturalidade">
                               <option value="Luanda">Luanda</option>
                               <option value="Cabinda">Cabinda</option>
                               <option value="Benguela">Benguela</option>
                               <option value="Huila">Huíla</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-residente" class="control-label">Trocar a foto</label>
                            <input type="file" name="foto" multiple id="ssi-upload" class="form-control"/>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="description">Quem Você é:</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Alterar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>  

                    </form>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Codigo AJAX

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var productId = $('#myForm').serialize();



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_func.php",
            data: productId,
            success:function(productId){
                alertigo('This is a LIGHT-BLUE alertigo.js notification message!', {color: 'light-blue'});
            }
        });         

    });
});
```

Redirecionando para o PHP

```
$panel_atual = "funcionario";

require "../config.php";

$id = intval($_POST['id_func']);
$nome =  $_POST['nome'];
$naturalidade =  $_POST['naturalidade'];
$residente =  $_POST['residente'];
$description =  $_POST['description'];
$imgvar_func = $_FILES['foto']['name']; 

if (file_exists("img_func/$imgvar_func")) {
    $a = 1;
    while (file_exists("img_func/[$a]$imgvar_func")) {
            $a++;
        }
        $imgvar_func = "[".$a."]".$imgvar_func;
}



$result_edit = "UPDATE funcionarios SET naturalidade='$naturalidade', residente='$residente', description = '$description', imagem = '$imgvar_func' WHERE id='$id_func' AND nome='$nome'";

$resultado_edit = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_edit); 
(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ssi-upload']['tmp_name'], "img_func/".$imgvar_func));


    if ($resultado_edit) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Dados alterados com sucesso!');window.location='index.php';</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('oops! Houve um problema. Tente novamente, por favor!');window.location='index.php';</script>";
    }
```

Comment: O arquivo update_func.php, está na mesma pasta?

Comment: Sim esta na mesma pasta